# Unable to save html file in Applications folder - Objective C/Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using the following line of code to download the contents of an html page and save it in a directory :

```
NSURL *yoyoyo = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"www.google.com"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:yoyoyo]; 
//NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL UrlWithString:url]];
//use this data to write to any path as documentdirectory path + filename.html
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *htmlFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.html"];
[data writeToFile:htmlFilePath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"Tile Directory: %@", documentsDirectory);
```

The documentsDirectory is :

```
Tile Directory: /Users/xxxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/D4B3A4CF-E7D0-4D25-A809-B3D3A170A329/Documents
```

But, however I am unable to see the html file when I got to the path where the file must be saved. I am unable to sort out the issue. Can someone please help ??

Comment: Is the NSData object not nil?

Comment: how wud I know whether it is nil or not ??

Comment: `if(!htmlFilePath) NSLog(@"Not nil");` -__- or `if(htmlFilePath != nil)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL UrlWithString:@"yourstringURL"]];
```

You need to change `"yourstringURL"` to some actual URL. If the URL does not exists or data can't be downloaded then your `data` variable will be `nil` and nothing will be written in a file.
P.S. You can also have the actual html string from the data variable with:

```
NSString *html = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]; //Remove the autorelease if using ARC
```

Then save the html to a file with:

```
[html writeToFile:htmlFilePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Comment: refer to the edits .. m sorry. I was using the url of google.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some error checking here.   In particular, check that the NSURL and NSData actually contain values (are not nil), and also verify that your paths object contains at least element before dereferencing.   Also, when you edited the post, you added a URL of "www.google.com", which is not a URL and likely won't resolve.   NSURL would prefer/require a fully-formed URL, such as "http://www.google.com", not a partial URL.

The most likely scenario for no file appearing is a `nil` value in `data`, as that would result in the write not executing.

While you are at it, though, I would suggest that you move to using `-[NSData -writeToURL:options:error:]` as it is a more modern API and will hand you back an appropriate error if there's a problem with writing out your data.

```
NSURL *htmlFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: htmlFilePath isDirectory: NO];
NSError *error=nil;
if (![data writeToURL: htmlFileURL options: NSDataWritingAtomic error: &error]) {
    NSLog( @"Error writing %@: %@", htmlFileURL, error);
}
```